# Управление каналами openAL

Tags: c++

Как разделить каналы стерео wav файла и отдельно усиливать и ослаблять каждый?

Comment: Если вам нужно поменять баланс один раз, можно сделать это самому, сразу при загрузке звука. Похоже, нет нормального способа делать это динамически. Можно при загрузке сделать две копии звука, в одной занулить левый канал, а во второй правый, и запустить их одновременно с разной громкостью.